# It is not a valid win32 application - Node v21

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, node.js, npm

I'm trying to ***"npm start"*** a project, but the error appears:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/swiper/swiper.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./node_modules/swiper/swiper.scss)
```

Message:

```
Error: \\?\C:\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-120\binding.node ***It is not a valid win32 application.***


\\?\C:\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-120\binding.node
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-id-swiper": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-share": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.13.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "swiper": "^6.3.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
```

**Node version: 21.0.0**

My computer is **x64**

Comment: https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Comment: @kosmos Should I downgrade the node? for which version?

Comment: I would try first upgrading `node-sass` to the latest. Looking at the support table v9.0.0 runs with Node 20. Also note that node-sass is currently deprecated.

Comment: @kosmos not work :( i used  "node-sass": "9.0.0" and `npm install node-sass@9.0.0`

Comment: At this point, if `npm i node-sass@latest` does not work, I would rather try with [dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) before downgrading Node.